# Redrawing a Planar Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

i got the idea of a planar graph is a graph that can be drawn without any edge crossings but whats the technique of redrawing it ?

Comment: I'd get some paper, try it loads of times until you get one which works.

Comment: This of course assumes that the graph is planar.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is to apply Kuratowski's theorem.

**Theorem.** *A graph is not planar if and only if it contains a subgraph which is a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.*

A subdivision of a graph is what you get by replacing one or more edges with paths.

In your case, if you replace the path $dcb$ with a single edge, you get $K_5$, so the graph *is* a subdivision of $K_5$, hence by Kuratowski's theorem it is not planar.  The "edge contraction" thing is probably a hint.

However, I do not know what tools you have at your disposal, so perhaps you are supposed to prove it is not planar by other means, and then discover that when you contract the edge you get $K_5$, and perhaps realize it is not a coincidence.

If the graph *were* planar, probably the best way to prove it is planar is by drawing it without crossings, by any means necessary.

Comment: Kuratowski's theorem might be overkill.  $K_5$ can be shown to be nonplanar using the Euler formula for planar graphs $F-E+V=2$.